# Error in OrientDB installation on Windows 10

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to install OrientDB 2.1.11 on Windows 10.
java version details are as follows:

java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)

Latest version of JDK is installed.
Getting the following error while running server.bat:

```
2016-03-02 00:53:31:482 INFO  OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=1,539MB (heap=455MB os=4,043MB disk=107,180MB) [orientechnologies]
2016-03-02 00:53:31:603 INFO  Loading configuration from: C:/OrientDB/orientdb-community-2.1.11/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2016-03-02 00:53:31:835 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.1.11 (build 2.1.x@rddb5c0b4761473ae9549c3ac94871ab56ef5af2c; 2016-02-15 10:45:12+0000) is starting up... [OServer]
2016-03-02 00:53:31:850 INFO  Databases directory: C:\OrientDB\orientdb-community-2.1.11\databases [OServer]
2016-03-02 00:53:31:888 INFO  Listening binary connections on 0.0.0.0:2424 (protocol v.32, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2016-03-02 00:53:31:904 INFO  Listening http connections on 0.0.0.0:2480 (protocol v.10, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tinkerpop/blueprints/IndexableGraph
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerNetworkListener.createCommand(OServerNetworkListener.java:126)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerNetworkListener.<init>(OServerNetworkListener.java:91)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:324)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tinkerpop.blueprints.IndexableGraph
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 30 more
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Michelle did you create the environment variable?

Comment: Hi @MichelaBonizzi.... Yes, i did create the environment variable ORIENTDB_HOME. The folder in which the database binaries are extracted is C:\OrientDB\orientdb-community-2.1.11. The same value is set for the environment variable. I read multiple posts and watched a couple of videos regarding installation. Nowhere was it mentioned to set the Environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

In the folder lib at your path C:/OrientDB/orientdb-community-2.1.11/
you should have the blueprints-core-2.6.0.jar.
Can you check to have it?